# @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap modals are taking longer time to open on iphone

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

In my Angular6 application @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap modals are very slow on mac safari browser and iphone(all browsers), but its working perfectly on other platforms(windows, ubuntu, Android). I am using AOT compilation option of angular. Should i use other modal?

Application Url : [here](https://booking.londonserenity.com/web/dist/)

Steps to replicate on safari iphone devices.

- Click on application Url
- Click on "view all treatments"
- Click on view info on any of the card.

Here is a stackblitz code sample [Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-iatagf)

Comment: The application url is not working.

Comment: @yougeen Thanks for your effort. As i checked url is working fine. Please copy link and paste in search bar. Please copy from here booking.londonserenity.com/web/dist/# and check once again.